# How do you defeat the Ancient Rock Wraith in the Deep Roads?

Tags: dragon-age-2

I really need help with this. I have it on Casual settings, but I still can't beat it. I've died around 10 times now.

My team is:

- Hawke:  Mage (Healing and Elemental)
- Merril: Mage (Elemental)
- Fenris: Warrior
- Varric: Ranged Rogue

I am not so sure if this is a good team.

I know to hide behind the pillars, but other than that I am stuck.

Comment: This fight it is imperative that you control your party members as well as Hawke. If you have gotten though the game by setting them on their own AI you will have problems. Some helpful tips. He is very weak to cold, but even using that he will take a while to go down. You can dodge his attacks by hiding behind pillars or in some cases just running. He has a lot of hp and defenses so if you have access to any stat reducing effects try to keep them up as much as possible. An in depth guide can be found here. http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Ancient_rock_wraith

Comment: It might be useful if you could at least tell us what you did on a typical attempt and what sort of weapons/armor you have for each party member. Even better, what spells/skills did you use? What are the stats like on each team member. Also did you control each member individually? We can give a more indepth analysis the more information you provide. At the moment, you haven't really given us much to go on.